# Do every Android version store the PIN/passwords at the same file?

Tags: password, android-versions

I find a *hateful* peculiarity of Android its nagging usual **changes between versions** in the paths for some system files and configuration variables. Even when I assume it is expectable on newborn operating systems.

I have read that the **PIN number** for unlocking the screen is stored (cyphered, I pressume) at `/data/system/password.key` .  So, for example, if I do:

```
# rm /data/system/password.key
```

... I will be able to delete it (of course priorly mounting the partition system as read/write, booting via Recovery, connecting via ADB shell, on a rooted device... blah blah blah).

Could this change **work on every version of Android**? Or this storage file is version-dependent?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/2012/02/28/cracking-pin-and-password-locks-on-android/)

> Android stores this pattern in a special file called password.key in /data/system/. As storing the pattern in plain text wouldn’t be very save, this time Android stores an salted SHA1-hashsum and MD5-hashsum of the PIN or password. The numeric PIN and the alphanumeric passwords are processed in the same way...
>
> Due to the fact that the hash is salted this time, its unfeasible to crack the password with help of a dictionary attack. For cracking the password it is important to get the salt and enough time for attempting a brute force attack. The salt is a string of the hexadecimal representation of a random 64-bit integer.

From this page it seems you are correct in believing that the password is located here in at least the 2.2 versions of Android and later.

Comment: And I can confirm (by my experience) that Android 5.0.2 also stores Password/PIN in the same file.

Comment: @Firelord, do you know if your Android version is 64 bits?

Comment: Confirmed for my 5.1 64 bit Android version.

Comment: Confirmed for my 4.3 Android. Or, at least, such file exists (it has 0 bytes long because I have no PIN defined).

Comment: Well, if we are going to believe that Spreitzenbarth (he seems and experienced programmer), and as long as his last post ( http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/2015/08/12/breaking-the-screenlock-a-short-update/ ) about the matter dates May 2015, I agree with Ch3mical Joe: every Android version stores the hash of the password into the same file.